# check if for every single char in string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make  `if`condition for a large number of chars.

I can use

```
if (str==!||str==@||str==#||str==$||str==^||str==&)
```

And so on, but this seems very inefficient. I would like to get the condition to work if the char is on of those:

```
!@#%$^&()_-+=\?/.,'][{}<>`~
```

Is there is any shorter and more efficient way of doing it?

```
for (var c0 = 1; c0 > fn.length++; c0++) {
 var str = fn.charAt(c0--);

 if (str ==-"!@#%$^&()_-+=\?/.,'][{}<>`~") {

 }
}
```

I want the check to accrue on every single char from the string above.

Comment: What you want is a Regular Expression. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to check if your character matches a particular character:

```
/^[\!@#%$\^&\(\)_\-\+=\?\/\.,'\]\[\{\}\<\>`~]$/
```

Here I have escape special characters so that they get treated like regular characters.

See working example below:

```js
const regex = /^[\!@#%$\^&\(\)_\-\+=\?\/\.,'\]\[\{\}\<\>`~]$/,
charA = '@', // appears in char set
charB = 'A'; // doesn't appear in char set

console.log(regex.test(charA)); // true
console.log(regex.test(charB)); // false
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use regular expressions you can instead put all your characters into an array and use `.includes` to check if your character is in your array.

```js
const chars = "!@#%$^&()_-+=\?/.,'][{}<>`~",
charArr = [...chars],
charA = '@', // is in char set
charB = 'A'; // isn't in char set

console.log(charArr.includes(charA)); // true
console.log(charArr.includes(charB)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular expressions rather than manual single character checking.

```
const pattern = new RegExp("!@#%$^&()_-+=\?\/.,'][{}<>`~");
const exists = pattern.test(str);

if (exists) { 
  // code logic for special character exists in string
}
```

Comment: @Andreas thanks update, that occurs when you are using / character inside the regex, since its a special character to regex it must be escaped by the \ character

Comment: You have to escape _all_ special characters when using `new RegExp(...)`

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `split('')` to split a string into an array of characters. Next you can use `.some` to check if a condition is true for at least one element in the array:

```
"!@#%$^&()_-+=\?/.,'][{}<>`~".split('').some(x => x === str)
```